# Usability of padding scheme in blinded RSA signature?

Tags: rsa, padding, blind-signature

In Wikipedia's article on [Blind signature](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blind_signature), in the section *Dangers of blind signing* which describes *RSA blinding attack* one reads the following

> This attack works because in this blind signature scheme the signer
>   signs the message directly. By contrast, in an unblinded signature
>   scheme the signer would typically use a padding scheme (e.g. by
>   instead signing the result of a cryptographic hash function applied to
>   the message, instead of signing the message itself), **however since the
>   signer does not know the actual message, any padding scheme would
>   produce an incorrect value when unblinded**.

Could someone please explain the meaning of the part I emphasized?

Comment: Padding adds a redundancy of a particular form. A random value almost certainly doesn't have that form and is rejected.

Comment: @CodesInChaos I have a feeling your *explanation* is on similar level of abstraction as the sentence I'm having problem with.

Comment: Also see [RSA blind signatures in practice](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/5626/10496).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the blind RSA signature scheme the blinding of a message
$m$ (to be blindly signed) is **multiplicative** with value $r^e$, where
you ensure that $r$ is invertible modulo $N$.

So if the sender receives the signed blinded message back from the
signer, he can unblind by multiplying with $r^{-1}$, yielding $s\equiv
m^d \pmod N$ which is a valid (textbook) RSA signature for $m$.

**Padding by the sender**

Note, that $m$ could also be the result of any [padding method for RSA
signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1#Schemes), which however
needs to be applied **by the sender** before blinding. By denoting this padding as $f$ we can simply 
consider the blinded message to be $m'\equiv f(m)r^e \pmod N$ (which clearly can be unblinded after blind signing).

**Padding by the signer**

Denoting the blinded message which is sent to the signer as $m'\equiv
mr^e \pmod N$, then padding **by the signer** means that the signer
changes the blinded message $m'\equiv mr^e \pmod N$ to some $m''$ before
signing. [Padding methods for RSA signatures](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PKCS_1#Schemes) hash the original
message (possibly with some parameters), padd the hash value to some
certain format and the result is then interpreted as an element in
$Z_N$, which is then exponentiated with the private signing exponent
$d$.

Observe that in doing so the signer padds an already blinded message and denote this padded blinded 
message as $m''=f(m')=f(mr^e)$. If such a padding to the message $m'$ received by the signer is applied **by the
signer**, then the signature obtained by the sender for $m''$ will be $s' \equiv (f(mr^e))^d \pmod N$ 
and then unblinding, i.e., computing $s'\cdot r^{-1} \equiv (f(mr^e))^d\cdot r^{-1} \pmod N$, 
will yield some element from $Z_N$ which is clearly not a valid signature $m^d\pmod N$ for the message $m$ the sender wants to be signed 
(for padding functions $f$ we assume to be applied, i.e., involving hashing. Clearly, if $f$ is the identity function then it works, but that is no padding).

Comment: If you have knowledge of standardized formatting/padding function for RSA Blind Signatures, then could you visit [Is there a standard padding/format for RSA Blind Signatures?](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/q/54085/10496)

Answer (score 1):

Answer by DrLecter looks incorrect.  Afaik almost all RSA padding schemes have been deprecated.  I believe unblinded RSA would use PSS padding today, but as I explained in https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/60728/764 any padding like PSS that directly takes randomness from the signer trivially violates blindness.

In fact, blind RSA *requires* a full domain hash (FDH) for padding, which PSS, etc. do not provide.  If you even truncate the padding to floor(log N), like PSS does I think, then you leak like 1/6th or 12th bit deanonymizing information per signature.  If leave many bits determined like some older ones, then your blind signature scheme becomes worthless.

You can implement FDH easily:  Frist, create a stream cipher S from the message hash. Second, run a loop that pull ceiling(log N) bit number r from S and repeats until r < N.  In other words our stream cipher's block counter keeps increasing.  Your loop terminates quickly because N should lie roughly half way between powers of two, but obviously you might explore tricks like avoiding N below say 1.3 * 2^floor(log N) or only looping on the top 256 bits of N.

There are way to incorporate randomness from the signer if you want to try to resurrect some shadow of PSS because we verify the padding when verifying the signature.

If you believe RSA-KTI, then there are no forgery attacks.  I'd incorporate the signer's public key N into the message hash anyways though, because doing so costs you nothing and prevents amortizing attacks on RSA-KTI across many RSA keys.