# Sequence of Encrypting RSA like Chaum Blinding scheme

Tags: encryption, rsa, blind-signature

I'd be a noob in cryptography but reading up a little on RSA, I do get some understanding and I want to specifically resolve this issue.

**UPDATED**

Lets say we have the following values in place:

```
KEYSIZE = 512  
HASHSIZE =  sha.digestsize*8 
digest = some SHA 512 function
```

We calculate the pub_key,pvt_key e,d via n = p*q
and totient function phy = (p-1)*(q-1) in effect getting 1 < e < tot_func
and we get d=e mod tot_func

**PS** : pub and pvt keys are created as an RSA_function(KEYSIZE)

Implementing an RSA scheme, we have a token m

Now

```
c(m) = m^e mod n
```

Decrypting it would be:

```
m = c^d mod n
```

**PS**: m is a token number (instead of padding a m=token hash, converted from some m=f(M))
To be specific:

```
m = convert_str_to_long(sha_digest(M))
```

M itself is of random HASHSIZE bits

---

#### Chaumian Blinding

I want to know where I'm going wrong with this.
Given the same scheme as above for token id m, However I want to be clear with a Chaum's blinding scheme and implement that instead.

we have n,p,q,d,e,m

To blind quoting from [Blinding](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blinding_%28cryptography%29)

> For example, in RSA blinding involves computing the blinding operation E(x) = x*r^e mod N, where r is a random integer between 1 and N and relatively prime to N (i.e. gcd(r, N) = 1), x is the ciphertext, e is the public RSA exponent and N is the RSA modulus. As usual, the decryption function f(z) = zd mod N is applied thus giving f(E(x)) = x^d*r^ed mod N = x^d*r mod N. Finally it is unblinded using the function D(z) = zr^−1 mod N. Since D(f(E(x))) = x^d mod N, this is indeed an RSA decryption. However, when decrypting in this manner, an adversary who is able to measure time taken by this operation would not be able to make use of this information (by applying timing attacks RSA is known to be vulnerable to) as she does not know the constant r and hence has no knowledge of the real input fed to the RSA primitives.

Blind requires creating a blinding factor,r.

```
while 1:
    r = random.getrandbits(KEYSIZE-1)
    Verify that GCD(r, n) ==1
    if gcd(r, n)==1: break;
```

- Create a blinding factor, r
- Create blinded_token = m * (r^e % n)

#### Questions:

- What the heck do you do after that? Decrypt > Unblind Or Unblind > Decrypt to recover token m?
- Also, if you want to **sign** the **blinded_token** do you Sign > Decrypt > Unblind OR Sign > Unblind > Decrypt ?
- How do you Unblind actually based on above blinding?

My goal is to recover back m.

Please do tell me if you need some more info. I need this asap.

Thanks in advance!

**UPDATE**
I would like to credit both [Rick](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/users/991/ricky-demer) and the [OP here](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5626/rsa-blind-signatures-in-practice?lq=1) in my work regarding this.
I got the solution finally.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A much better way to choose `r` is

```
while 1:
    s = random.getrandbits(KEYSIZE+privacyparameter)
    r = 1+(s%(n-1))
    if gcd(r,n) == 1: break;
```

.
privacyparameter is chosen by the blinder.

If $\:$ gcd(m,n) = 1 $\:$ then the [statistical distance](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_distance) between the distribution of blinded_token and

the uniform distribution on units mod n is less $\:$ n/((2^(KEYSIZE+privacyparameter+1))-(2*n)) $\;$.

The signer does not need to know or care what that value is.

It's much better to create $\;\;$  blinded_token $\:$=$\:$ (m * (r^e % n)) % n $\;\;$,

so that the size of the output won't leak much information about `m`.

The signer computes $\:$ [(blinded_token)^d % n](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_exponentiation) $\:$ and sends that to the blinder. $\:$ If the signer instead

signed or decrypted the token in the standard way, then the blind signature scheme wouldn't work.

If $\;\;$ (signers_response)^e % n $\:$=$\:$ blinded_token $\;\;$ then output

((signers_response)*[modinv](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Modular_multiplicative_inverse)(r,n)) % n $\;$ as the unblinded signature, else reject.

There are two further subtleties for this blind signature scheme:

gcd(blinded_token,n) = 1 $\;$ if and only if $\;$ gcd(m,n) = 1

However, as alluded to in the one of the OP's comments to this answer,

the hash can to chosen to guarantee that $\:$ gcd(m,n) = 1 $\;$.

(So, hopefully, "sha_digest" is something that does so, rather than *just* one of the SHA functions.)

Also, if [the RSA function does not define a permutation over $\mathbb{Z}_n^*$](http://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007%2F978-3-642-34961-4_25#page-1), then blindness

does not necessarily hold even if all relevant values of `m` satisfy gcd(m,n) = 1.

Comment: what's the privacy parameter in random.getrandbits(KEYSIZE+privacyparameter)  ? pvt key?

Comment: How do you sign after blinding? sign = Blinded_message**d?
I mean Blinded_message number is long long long.. and equally for d! multiplying them would take gazillion years. What am I doing wrong or what do I need to do now?

Comment: How do you sign after blinding? sign = Blinded_message**d?
I mean Blinded_message number is long long long.. and equally for d! multiplying them would take gazillion years. What am I doing wrong or what do I need to do now?

Comment: gcd(m,n) = 1  in my case

Comment: see i need to know how "privacyparameter is chosen by the blinder". how does one create the privacy parameter? Also how can signing r**d where r and d are enormous be possible?

Comment: Neither party computes r**d. $\;\;\;$ (You may want to actually look at the link I gave for $\:$ (blinded_token)^d % n $\;$.) $\;\;\;$ I'm about to edit in a bound on the blindness in terms of privacyparameter. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: Then how do sign on a blinded_message?
If you see here: http://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/5626/rsa-blind-signatures-in-practice
the guy lists down Signature of a Blinded message=Blinded message^d

Comment: Which of the posts in that link are you talking about? $\;\;\;$ One signs on a blinded_message by computing $\:$ (blinded_message)^d % n $\;$. $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: yes, but pow(blinded_message,d,n) is taking wayyy long. Inshort I dont even know if it will throw back a memory overflow! so how do you tackle this? Would it be possible for you to describe this with an example in your solution above step by step?
blinded_message and d if KEYSIZE - even 128, takes a long time. how do you do that? Even if it succeeds unblinded_signed_msg = pow(signed_msg,r**-1,n) 
how will you check the signature authenticity?
Will unblinded_signed_msg == pow(message,d,n) satisfy?

Comment: Are you using Python? $\:$ Is "wayyy to long" more than 15 seconds? $\:$ My laptop was able to evaluate that for 25 random 2047-bit triples in under 7 seconds. $\:$ I would tackle this by making sure you're never computing pow(blinded_message,d), and then looking for other bugs you might have. $\:$ As far as I can see, the value of pow(signed_msg,r**-1,n) is completely irrelevant. $\:$ (I don't see a reason for anything involving r to be in the exponent.) $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: One would check the signature's authenticity by checking whether or not $\:$ pow(claimed_signature,e,n) == digest(message) $\:$ is satisfied. $\;\;\;$ "Will unblinded_signed_msg == pow(message,d,n) satisfy" what condition? $\;\;\;\;\;\;$

Comment: ok thts something.under 15 secs. u said one to chk sig authenticity.thats wat i meant by  unblinded_signed_msg == pow(message,d,n);

Comment: u say pow(claimed_signature,e,n) == digest(message) well isn't signed_blind_msg = ((blinded_message)**d)%n itself? isthat what im doing wrong?

Comment: Else how are you generating the signature?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/13893/discussion-between-user2290820-and-ricky-demer)